# Align text in center of toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my application I am using a `Toolbar`. Now I want the title(label) to be displayed in the center of the Toolbar. When the home button (back button) is not shown then the title comes in the center, but when the back button is there the text moves little further from center. So how can I do this?

#### XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_list_detail"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ld_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

#### Code

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_list_detail);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
tvHeader = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_ld_header);
//rlToolbar = (RelativeLayout) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.rl_toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a custom title in your Toolbar all you need to do is remember is that Toolbar is just a fancy ViewGroup so you can add a custom title like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This means that you can style the TextView however you would like because it's just a regular TextView. So in your activity you can access the title like so:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Answer (score -2):

To center the Title in your Toolbar you must add android:layout_gravity="center" delete android:gravity="center" change android:layout_width="match_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content" in your TextView.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_ld_header"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Hello"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
   android:textStyle="bold" />`
```